# Can't connect from IIS to localDB

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, visual-studio

I'm trying to develop a WebService between me and my roomate (so a local one).

I created a Database (.mdf) saved in one of my folders and some aspx pages that access to it and retrieve informations. 
Now I was trying to deploy the project under IIS and I'm getting a problem when I have to access to the local db.

> provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 Server not found or not
>   accessible.

Everything from Web Visual Studio works fine! So if I try to connect the DB just running from VS on Google Chrome everything is fine. This error appears only when I try to run it under IIS 8.0

```
(my string connection = Server=(LocalDB)\\v11.0;     

AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\Asus\\Desktop\\RobaMia\\SQLSERVER\\WindowsFormsApplication3\\WindowsFormsApplication3\\Database2.mdf;
Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=False)
```

Could it be that `"User Instance = False"` makes the trick?

---

I say also that all my application pools are user-set
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ii8Rb.jpg

Answer (score 3):

Probably your IIS Application Pool doesn't have permission to open your database file C:\Users\Asus\Desktop\RobaMia\SQLSERVER\WindowsFormsApplication3\WindowsFormsApplication3\Database2.mdf. I would suggest to change the application pool identity to your local windows user.

See this link: [Using LocalDB with Full IIS, Part 1: User Profile - SQL Server Express WebLog - Site Home - MSDN Blogs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2011/12/09/using-localdb-with-full-iis-part-1-user-profile.aspx)

Comment: The path is currently `C:\Users\<your account>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances`

If your app pools are using "ApplicationPoolIdentity" then you can grant permission to the db files or folder to `IIS AppPool\<app pool name>`.  You really dont want to give a web app the same permissions as a higher permission desktop user.

Answer (score 2):

I too had the same problem.

1. From the visual studio disconncect the data connection from the
   server explorer to the reference database.(It allows to copy the file)
2. Publish your project as you do , personally I do file system.
3. Copy App_Data manually form the your local project to the published path.
4. In IIS double    click the Application Pools.
5. Click on "Set Application Pool Default" in right top corner of the explorer.
6. Under Process Model go to identity and select "Local System"
7. Done Good luck.

It works for all the web api that you are testing in iis. It worked for my xamrine.android app testing only when hosted in IIS and not in Express.

Comment: Granting localsystem is fine as a temporary troubleshooting step, but its too much permission to leave in place.

Answer (score 0):

I had this in my web.config. Removing it fixed the issue for me

`<identity impersonate="true" /`>